# AWS CodePipeline Pipeline does not update

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

### What I have:

1. I have 2 CodeCommit Repo. 1st repo contains the CDK code and 2nd repo contains service code.
2. 3 files in the CDK repo which does the following:

   1. `pipeline-stack.ts` - Creates a Pipeline and adds the 2 repos using `CodeCommitSourceAction`. Note, this is the codepipeline.Pipeline Construct.

```
export type Props = StackProps & {
    pipelineName: string,
    sourcePackages: string[]
}
export class PipelineStack extends Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: Props) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        this.codePipeline = this.createPipeline(this, props);
    }

    private createPipeline = (app: Construct, props: Props): Pipeline => {
        const { pipelineName, sourcePackages } = props;
        const pipeline = new Pipeline(this, pipelineName, {
            pipelineName: pipelineName,
        });
        const actions: Array<IAction> = [];

        sourcePackages.forEach(sourcePackage => {
            const actionName = `${sourcePackage}-action-name`.toLowerCase();
            const outputArtifact = new Artifact(`${sourcePackage}-output-artifact`.toLowerCase());

            actions.push(new CodeCommitSourceAction({
                actionName,
                repository: Repository.fromRepositoryName(app, sourcePackage, sourcePackage),
                output: outputArtifact,
                branch: 'mainline'
            }));
        });

        pipeline.addStage({
            stageName: 'Source',
            actions,
        });

        return pipeline;
    }
}
```

2. `ConversationServiceBuildStack` - Creates a `Build` Stage that contains a `CodeBuildAction` which builds a Docker image of the 2nd repo and pushes it in a ECR repo.

```
type Props = StackProps & {
    pipeline: Pipeline;
}

export class ConversationServiceBuildStack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: Props) {

        const buildImage = new Project(scope, "BuildImage", {
            buildSpec: BuildSpec.fromSourceFilename("app/buildspec.yaml"),
            source: Source.codeCommit({ repository: cdkCodeCommitRepo }),
            environment: {
                privileged: true,
                environmentVariables: {
                    AWS_ACCOUNT_ID: { value: Account.Beta },
                    REGION: { value: AwsRegion.US_EAST_1 },
                },
            },
        });

        ecrRepo.grantPullPush(buildImage);
        cdkCodeCommitRepo.grantRead(buildImage);
        serviceCodeCommitRepo.grantPullPush(buildImage);

        // Creates the build stage for CodePipeline
        const buildArtifact = new Artifact("BuildArtifact");
        props.pipeline.addStage({
            stageName: 'Build',
            actions: [
                new CodeBuildAction({
                    actionName: "DockerBuildPush",
                    input: new Artifact(),
                    project: buildImage,
                    outputs: [buildArtifact],
                }),
            ],
        });
    }
}
```

3. `app.ts` - The app.ts, which is entrypoint of the CDK project

```
const app = new cdk.App();
const pipeline = new PipelineStack(app, 'DemoPipelineId', {
    pipelineName: 'ConversationServiceCdkPipeline',
    sourcePackages: pipelinePackages,
    env: { account: 'XXXX', region: 'us-east-1' },
});

new ConversationServiceBuildStack(pipeline, 'DemoBuildStack', {
    pipeline: pipeline.codePipeline,
})

app.synth();
```

### What is happening:

1. Once the pipeline is deployed the first time manually, it gets auto triggered when there is a new commit in any of the 2 repos.
2. But, Any subsequent changes in the pipeline Build Stage does not reflect when the `CodeBuild` project is running.

### What I am confused about/ Have questions about:

1. Do I need to run CDK Synth and manually Deploy the pipeline from my local computer every time the Pipeline related code changes?
2. Anyway to automate the process? Something like, a another stage called `CDKBuild`.
3. Reading from [**this**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.CodePipeline.html#example) example, The Pipeline.CodePipeline Construct has a SynthStep where we supply cdk synth command. Do we need something similar for the CodePipeline.Pipeline construct?

### What I want:

1. The pipeline should auto update when the CDK code changes. For example, I added a new environment variable in the `CodeBuild` Project.